# Set <select> default value with redux-form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

This is above my paygrade. I was trying to put a dropdown list in `redux-form` and have it initialize with a default value like its done for `<input>`.

The custom drop down component is setup as follows:

```
const renderDropDownField = ({ input, label, values, defaultValue }) => (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col sm="6">
        <label className="input-label">{label}</label>
      </Col>
      <Col sm="6">
        <Row>
          <select className="dropdown-list" {...input} >
            {values.map((value, index) => (
              <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </Row>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
```

Then the field in the form

```
  <Field
    name="shuffle"
    component={renderDropDownField}
    label="SHUFFLE [ YES/NO ]:"
    values={props.list.shuffle.values}         // from parent
    defaultValue={props.list.shuffle.default}  // from parent
  />
```

The `defaultValue` prop in the field is extra because the initial values come from the  `defaultValues` from `mapStateToprops`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  enableReinitialize: false,
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
  initialValues: props.defaultValues
})
```

I have tried every permutation of setting the `value`, `defaultValue`, and `selected` attribute in the `<select>` or `<option>` tag with no luck.

> How can we set the initial value, or the default value in a drop down list?

The actual form value is set correctly but the option is not set in the gui.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify for anyone else looking at this thread in the future. The `defaultValue` prop is not necessary at all in the `renderDropDownField` function. Nor do you have to specify an attribute `defaultValue` in the `<select>` or `<option>`.

Say in the `{ initialValues: props.defaultValues }` one is passing all the default values for all fields including the default value for our `<select>` component. Example:

```
this.state = {
  defaultValues: {
    shuffle: "No"
  }
};
```

and the options for the list like so

```
this.dropdownListOptions = {
    shuffle: {
      values: ["Yes","No"]
    }
  };
```

Then the `redux-form` will automatically load the default value in the form and gui as long as the default value i.e.: in the state matches one of the values in the option list. This was my problem. I had a value in the state which was different than all values in the option.  The answer below help me troubleshoot it.

Comment: initialValues might help here: https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried passing defaultValue prop to select?

```
const renderDropDownField = ({ input, label, values, defaultValue }) => (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col sm="6">
        <label className="input-label">{label}</label>
      </Col>
      <Col sm="6">
        <Row>
          <select defaultValue={defaultValue} className="dropdown-list" {...input} >
            {values.map((value, index) => (
              <option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </Row>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
```

Comment: Can you check if you're actually getting the defaultValue in renderDropDownComponent

Comment: I have added a console.log statement and its coming in fine.

Comment: The defaultValue has nothing to do with redux-form. You can see a sample code here using only react. https://repl.it/repls/EmbellishedOrangeredDecimals

Comment: Your solution works. The value passed through props.default values did not match any of the list options.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the JSX attribute **defaultValue={...}**

```js
<Row className="form-group">
    <Label htmlFor="rating" xs={12}>Rating</Label>
    <Col xs={12}>
        <Control.select model=".rating" name="rating" id="rating"className="form-control" 

            **defaultValue={1}**              >

              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
        </Control.select>
    </Col>
</Row>
```